# How do I set the favicon used when serving files from DNN Platform?

Tags: dotnetnuke

When serving static files (e.g. PDFs) from a DNN website, the default DNN favicon shows up, rather than the favicon configured for the site. How can we get the site's main favicon to be used when serving static files?

Answer (score 0):

When serving static files, DNN isn't part of the request. There's also not a way for the web server to tell the browser an alternate location for the favicon. So the browser looks in the default location, `/favicon.ico`. A DNN favicon is included here in the default installation package. Assuming you aren't hosting sites with different favicons in your DNN installation, you can simply overwrite DNN's `favicon.ico` file in the root of the file system with your custom `favicon.ico` file (this will require access to the web server's file system, it's not exposed through the web interface by default).

If you host multiple sites with different `favicon.ico` files, there's not as simple of an answer here. You could probably use [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) rules to read the host being used in the request, and redirect `/favicon.ico` requests to the correct spot.